# Which Spring security ACL option is best for hierarchical permissions

Tags: gwt, spring-security, acl

I am developing a GWT application which im using Spring Security to handle the authentication. My application will have 5 users each with different roles.

1. Superuser - This is the site owner and has read write access to everything.
2. School owner - This is a person who owns school(s) that will use the application. This user has access to all their school(s).
3. District manager - This is an employee of the site owner and has read access to the schools in that district. (A district is a physical area with a number of schools)
4. School manager - Manages a particular school and has read and write access to everything on that school. Access is given by the school owner.
5. Instructor - Has read and write access to only particular areas assigned to him/her by the school manager.

Ive taken a look at different ways to implement such a security model and I'm torn between two ways of solving it using Spring security, first there's the complex way of doing it by using 4 database ACL tables as explained [on denksoft blog](http://www.denksoft.com/wordpress/web-development/acl-spring-security-tutorial/)

The other way is to use Expression-Based Access Control through Spring security Expression language which is much easier and doesn't require extra database tables.

MY question is, from what I intend to achieve, which option is better to use and would give better results. I assume using the first option (using database ACL tables) offers more customization. I'm from a RoR background and wonder why i'd need so many tables to achieve this. Is the Expression language option a viable solution for this scenario. And if so is there a nice starting point/tutorial for this? Advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACL may be overkill in this situation.

When checking for authorization, Spring EL should be enough, e.g.:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_School-owner') or hasRole('ROLE_School-manager')")
```

If the roles are hierarchical, then things get even easier once you group roles, by using one more level of indirection:

Group "School owner": roles ROLE_School-owner + ROLE_School-manager + ROLE_Instructor

Group "School manager": roles ROLE_School-manager + ROLE_Instructor

Then, if you need to check for school manager authorization, you only need to check for that role:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_School-manager')")
```

This will also give permission to a user of group "School owner", since that group also has assigned the role of school manager.